# Android parcelable issue relating to bitmaps

Tags: android, parcelable

For some reason occasionally when my Vehicle object is passed as a parcelable to another activity it breaches the maximum size:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException:
>   data parcel size 569848 bytes

However the strange thing is this does not happen everytime. In my app I have an image and when I click it then it passes it to another activity. After multiple times of clicking this same image eventually it results in that exception. I am compressing the Bitmap as well. Does anyone know the issue?

I should also note if I compress with 30 I also have the same issue

```
package com.example.daniel.carbudgy.misc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.example.daniel.carbudgy.R;
import com.example.daniel.carbudgy.tasks.ImageDownloaderCallback;
import com.example.daniel.carbudgy.tasks.ImageDownloaderTask;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by daniel on 11/09/17.
 */

public class Vehicle implements Parcelable {
    public interface VehicleHandler {
        public void ready();
    }

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String colour;
    private String imageSrc;
    private Drawable image;
    private VehicleHandler handler;

    public Vehicle(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.colour = in.readString();
        this.imageSrc = in.readString();

        int length = in.readInt();
        byte[] buf = new byte[length];
        in.readByteArray(buf);

        // Convert Bitmap to Drawable:
        image = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buf, 0, length));
    }
    public Vehicle(JSONObject vehicle_json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject manufacture = vehicle_json.getJSONObject("manufactureModel").getJSONObject("manufacture");
        JSONObject model = vehicle_json.getJSONObject("manufactureModel").getJSONObject("model");
        String vehicle_name = manufacture.getString("manufacture") + " " + model.getString("model");
        Integer vehicle_id = vehicle_json.getInt("vehicleId");
        String image_src = vehicle_json.getJSONObject("imageUpload").getString("url");
        String colour = vehicle_json.getJSONObject("colour").getString("colour");
        setId(vehicle_id);
        setName(vehicle_name);
        setColour(colour);
        setImageSrc(image_src);
        image = null;
        handler = null;
    }

    public static final Creator<Vehicle> CREATOR = new Creator<Vehicle>() {
        @Override
        public Vehicle createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Vehicle(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Vehicle[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Vehicle[size];
        }
    };

    public void setHandler(VehicleHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void load() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageSrc);
            new ImageDownloaderTask(new ImageDownloaderCallback() {
                @Override
                public void success(Drawable[] drawables) {
                    image = drawables[0];
                    handler.ready();
                }

                @Override
                public void fail() {

                }
            }).execute(url);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getImageSrc() {
        return imageSrc;
    }

    public void setImageSrc(String imageSrc) {
        this.imageSrc = imageSrc;
    }

    public Drawable getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Drawable image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(getId());
        parcel.writeString(getName());
        parcel.writeString(getColour());
        parcel.writeString(getImageSrc());

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ((BitmapDrawable)getImage()).getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, out);
        parcel.writeInt(out.size());
        parcel.writeByteArray(out.toByteArray());
    }


}
```

Comment: Kudos, you were actually able to replicate the error, I too was stuck on this same error, what I would recommend is don't pass Bitmap in intent, but save it in internal storage and send the address of the bitmap and fetch it in next activity

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know the issue?

Do not pass a `Bitmap` in `Intent` extras, in the saved instance state `Bundle`, etc. Instead, pass information that allows the other party to use the bitmap:

- By pulling it from some bitmap cache in your process
- By loading the bitmap from its original source again (e.g., an `https` URL)

There is a 1MB limit on Binder-based IPC transactions. That limit is on **all outstanding transactions**, and so multiple simultaneous transactions' combined memory usage needs to be below 1MB. As a result, the variance that you are seeing can be from:

- Varying memory footprints from the `Bitmap` itself, based on resolution, or
- Varying other IPC transactions that are going on at the time

Your objective is to ensure that any such transaction — passing an `Intent` outside of your process, for example — should be nowhere near that 1MB limit, so even if there are a few transactions going on at once, the combined total does not reach 1MB.

Comment: How about this then? An ObjectRepository class where I can store any object and I will get an Id back. I can then pass that Id through the intents so that other activites can access it. My only concern then is preventing garbage collection as I will have a reference to the objects in the ObjectRepository.

Comment: This class would also be static

Comment: and more importantly why doesn't android allow you to pass references of objects through activities. Why do they have to be serialized.

Comment: @DanielMcCarthy: "why doesn't android allow you to pass references of objects through activities" -- because the other activity is not necessarily in your same process. For example, it may be an activity from another app.

Comment: Thank you for your response